# Error on CHECK constraint in HANA SQL

Tags: sql, hana

I'm trying to create a table in the SQL Console of the catalog editor on a HANA SPS12 system with this statement:

```
create table testEmployee (
empid   varchar(4) primary key,
salary number(6),
CHECK (salary >= 50000 and salary <= 200000)
```

)

It works if I change the CHECK into two separate statements but when I use the statement with the and I get this error:

```
12:25:20 PM (SQL Editor) Could not execute 'create table testEmployee ( empid varchar(4) primary key, salary number(6), CHECK ...'Error: (dberror) 288 - cannot use duplicate table name: TESTEMPLOYEE: line 2 col 13 (at pos 13)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ross

Comment: You apparently already have a table named `testEmployee` - the error unrelated to the check constraint

Comment: No, I don't have a table named testEmployee.  I double and tripled checked that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a wrong error message (aka bug) to me.
The problem does not occur when stating the check condition like this:

```
create table testEmployee (
             empid   varchar(4) primary key,
             salary number(6),
       CHECK (salary between 50000 and 200000)
);
```

In my tests it seemed to me that

A) one can create multiple check constraints by running multiple `ALTER TABLE ADD CHECK` commands, like so:

```
create  table checker (
    empid   varchar(4) primary key,
    salary number(6) 
    );

alter table checker add CHECK ( salary + empid > 100);  
alter table checker add CHECK ( mod(salary/empid, 2)= 1);  
alter table checker add CHECK ( salary between 1000 and 50000);
```

B) every single `CHECK CONSTRAINT` can appear on reference each column **once**. So, `SALARY BETWEEN 5000 and 200000` works, while the logical equivalent `SALARY >= 5000 and SALARY <= 200000` results in the error message.

**UPDATE**: the problem with the wrong error message does not occur on HANA 2SP02 and newer.